# Does vscommunity.exe /layout include all packages [cmd offline download for visual studio community 2015]?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

For starters, its really annoying trying to install individual packages after installing visual studio community 2015. I've been trying to install the cordova tools update 4 but to no avail, the installation progress hangs almost halfway and its been installing for 3 days now. The max. installation time i've ever had from other users is normally 9hrs max...

Just want a solid answer on the way around this. **My final option** is to install a windows afresh and try installing vs community 2015 again, but before i go through another long wait, i would like to know if the **cmd offline method ( /layout) includes all packages especially the javascript cordova tools.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the /layout option will download most of the tools required for the setup,  there are other 3rd party components that still require an internet connection like Android SDK.

If you still have problems with the install, you can contact me directly (rmpablos_at_microsoft_dot_com) and we will investigate your setup issues reviewing your log files.